# Capistrano: Check if a folder in Git has changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

Our app (1 repo) has a Rails backend and an Angular frontend. As such, the deployment process has an `npm install, bower install, grunt build --force` at some point. The problem is that it takes a long time to deploy, since these commands are still executed even though we are just updating Rails-related things.

Is there some kind of hook so that I can check that `if the folder containing frontend code has changes, then npm install`? Or should we just split the repo into two repos with their own deploy processes each?

Answer (score 0):

[apistrano-faster-assets](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-faster-assets) plugins enables such functionality for plain Rails assets.

You might want to check the [core task to see how that's done](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-faster-assets/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/faster_assets.rake#L19-42) and adapt or copy-paste the code for your use.

Here's my attempt to extract only the relevant steps and provide some more comments:

```
class PrecompileRequired < StandardError; end
begin
  # get the previous release
  latest_release = capture(:ls, '-xr', releases_path).split[1]

  # precompile if this is the first deploy
  raise PrecompileRequired unless latest_release

  # create a 'Pathname' object for latest_relase
  latest_release_path = releases_path.join(latest_release)

  # execute raises if there is a diff
  execute(:diff, '-Naur', release_path.join('path/to/frontend/code'), latest_release_path.join('path/to/frontend/code')) rescue raise(PrecompileRequired)

  info("Skipping asset precompile, no asset diff found")

  # copy over all of the assets from the last release
  execute(:cp, '-r', latest_release_path.join('public', fetch(:assets_prefix)), release_path.join('public', fetch(:assets_prefix)))

rescue PrecompileRequired
  # execute compile command here
end
```