# How do I get the path for the release being deployed in Capistrano 3?

Tags: capistrano3

During my deploy process, I need to create a symbolic link to the correct version of a configuration file, which depends on the environment. While I expected that to be trivial, I could not find anywhere how to get the current path.

I need to operate on the release directory *before* the `current` symbolic link is switched to it. `release_path` yields the path to the `current` directory, rather than something like `releases/20170131090326/`.

```
namespace :deploy do
    desc 'Link daemon configuration file'
    task :link_daemon_config do
        on roles(:batch) do
            execute "ln -s #{release_path}/app/config/daemon_prod.config #{release_path}/app/config/daemon.config"
        end
    end
    after :updated, :link_daemon_config
end
```

I do have ideas for a workaround; the question is just about how could I refer to the current directory and where can I find information like this in the future.

Thank you

Comment: This should work, although it will behave differently depending on whether you are running it as part of a deployment or standalone.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not although I thought it would have. As i wrote above, the variable contains the path to the _current_ link, which is not what I need since I'd want to do my task before the switch.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this in a similar use-case. Make sure keep-releases is set to a number higher than 2. e.g `set :keep_releases, 3`

Try this:

```
namespace :deploy do
    desc 'Link daemon configuration file'
    task :link_daemon_config do
        on roles(:batch) do
            last_release = capture(:ls, "-xt", releases_path).split[1]
            last_release_path = releases_path.join(last_release)
            execute "ln -s #{last_release_path}/app/config/daemon_prod.config #{release_path}/app/config/daemon.config"
        end
    end
    after :updated, :link_daemon_config
end
```

Useful links: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake#L184

Similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26267220/15500541